# cannot find webflow plugin?

Tags: grails, gradle, grails-3.3

I created a sample grails 3 app and added webflow plugin into build.gradle as follows

```
compile "org.grails.plugins:webflow:2.1.0"
```

here is the link to the plugin

https://grails.org/plugin/webflow?skipRedirect=true

When i run compile i get the following error

```
Error |
Error initializing classpath: Could not find :webflow:2.1.0.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/C:/Users/user/.m2/repository//webflow/2.1.0/webflow-2.1.0.pom
    file:/C:/Users/user/.m2/repository//webflow/2.1.0/webflow-2.1.0.jar
    https://repo.grails.org/grails/core//webflow/2.1.0/webflow-2.1.0.pom
    https://repo.grails.org/grails/core//webflow/2.1.0/webflow-2.1.0.jar
```

Do you know why i am getting this error? Why cannot grails find the plugin? I appreciate any help!

My Grails version is 3.3.2

Comment: Did you try: ./gradlew build --refresh-dependencies ? And how does your build.gradle look like?

Comment: It seems Grails 3 with webflow is not yet supported: 
https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/601

Comment: thanks ill try to break the webflow dependency.